# Avoid the use of Java data structures in Apache Spark to avoid copying the data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a MySQL database with a single table containing about 100 million records (~25GB, ~5 columns). Using Apache Spark, I extract this data via a JDBC connector and store it in a DataFrame. 
From here, I do some pre-processing of the data (e.g. replacing the NULL values), so I absolutely need to go through each record. 
Then I would like to perform dimensionality reduction and feature selection (e.g. using PCA), perform clustering (e.g. K-Means) and later on do the testing of the model on new data.

I have implemented this in Spark's Java API, but it is too slow (for my purposes) since I do a lot of copying of the data from a DataFrame to a java.util.Vector and java.util.List (to be able to iterate over all records and do the pre-processing), and later back to a DataFrame (since PCA in Spark expects a DataFrame as input).

I have tried extracting information from the database into a org.apache.spark.sql.Column but cannot find a way to iterate over it. 
I also tried avoiding the use of Java data structures (such as List and Vector) by using the org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{DenseVector, SparseVector}, but cannot get that to work either. 
Finally, I also considered using JavaRDD (by creating it from a DataFrame and a custom schema), but couldn't work it out entirely.

After a lengthy description, my question is: is there a way to do all steps mentioned in the first paragraph, without copying all the data into a Java data structure? 
Maybe one of the options I tried could actually work, but I just can't seem to find out how, as the docs and literature on Spark are a bit scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the wording of your question, it seems there is some confusion about the stages of Spark processing.

First, we tell Spark what to do by specifying inputs and transformations. At this point, the only things that are known are (a) the number of partitions at various stages of processing and (b) the schema of the data. `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` is used at this stage to identify the metadata associated with a column. However, it doesn't contain any of the data. In fact, there is no data at all at this stage.

Second, we tell Spark to execute an action on a dataframe/dataset. This is what kicks off processing. The input is read and flows through the various transformations and into the final action operation, be it `collect` or `save` or something else.

So, that explains why you cannot "extract information from the database into" a `Column`.

As for the core of your question, it's hard to comment without seeing your code and knowing exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish but it is safe to say that much migrating between types is a bad idea.

Here are a couple of questions that might help guide you to a better outcome:

- Why can't you perform the data transformations you need by operating directly on the `Row` instances?
- Would it be convenient to wrap some of your transformation code into a UDF or UDAF?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sim, you wrote a few quite useful, conceptual things, these will be very useful for me. In the meantime. I managed to solve my issue(s) by using UDFs on Dataframes. Also, Spark 2.0.0 Preview provides a lot of additional functionality, so porting my code to 2.0.0 made it easier to use Datasets exclusively (vs. copying data to java Vector/List)

Comment: Yes, if you are using relatively simple data structures, `Datasets` in 2.0.0 should work well.